# ShowCaseView Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, showcaseview, samsung-galaxy

I`m having some trouble with the Galaxy S family, the showcase view works flawless in any other device, but I get the following error on Galaxy S devices.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5760012 byte allocation with 3573238 free bytes and 3MB until OOM at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java) at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3747)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620) at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852) at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompatApi21.getDrawable(ResourcesCompatApi21.java)
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(ResourcesCompat.java)
at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.StandardShowcaseDrawer.(StandardShowcaseDrawer.java)
at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.(ShowcaseView.java)
at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.(ShowcaseView.java)
at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView$Builder.(ShowcaseView.java)
at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView$Builder.(ShowcaseView.java)
at br.com.mygas.myapplication.MainActivity.showcase(MainActivity.java)
at br.com.mygas.myapplication.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java)
at br.com.mygas.myapplication.MainActivity$5.onShowcaseViewDidHide(MainActivity.java)
at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView$2.onAnimationEnd(ShowcaseView.java)
at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.AnimatorAnimationFactory$2.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorAnimationFactory.java)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1089)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:666)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:682)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590) at
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559) at
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

## And this is the code implemented that produces the above error:

```
private void showcase() {
        if (SaveSharedPreference.isMainActivity(this)) {
            switch (counter) {
                case 0:
                    new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                            .withMaterialShowcase()
                            .setContentTitle("Esta é a tela inicial:")
                            .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseThemeNext)
                            .setShowcaseEventListener(new SimpleShowcaseEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onShowcaseViewDidHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {
                                    counter++;
                                    showcase();
                                }
                            })
                            .build();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle("Selecione o tipo de combustível:")
                            .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.spinner, this))
                            .setShowcaseDrawer(new CustomShowcaseView(this, findViewById(R.id.spinner).getWidth(), findViewById(R.id.spinner).getHeight()))
                            .setShowcaseEventListener(new SimpleShowcaseEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onShowcaseViewDidHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {
                                    counter++;
                                    showcase();
                                }
                            })
                            .build();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                            .withMaterialShowcase()
                            .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.fab2, this))
                            .setContentTitle("Clique neste botão para procurar combustível ao redor:")
                            .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseThemeNext)
                            .setShowcaseEventListener(new SimpleShowcaseEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onShowcaseViewDidHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {
                                    counter++;
                                    showcase();
                                }
                            })
                            .build();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                            .withMaterialShowcase()
                            .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.fab2, this))
                            .setContentTitle("Lembre-se:")
                            .setContentText("É necessário estar com o GPS ligado")
                            .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme2)
                            .setShowcaseEventListener(new SimpleShowcaseEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onShowcaseViewDidHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {
                                    counter++;
                                    showcase();
                                }
                            })
                            .build();
                    SaveSharedPreference.mainActivityFirst(this);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't work out where the error is coming from so looking for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved changing the method hide from ShowcaseView.java
From this:

```
@Override
    public void hide() {
        // If the type is set to one-shot, store that it has shot
        shotStateStore.storeShot();
        mEventListener.onShowcaseViewHide(this);
        fadeOutShowcase();
    }
```

To this:

```
@Override
    public void hide() {
        // If the type is set to one-shot, store that it has shot
        clearBitmap();
        shotStateStore.storeShot();
        mEventListener.onShowcaseViewHide(this);
        fadeOutShowcase();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**OutOfMemoryError** is the most common problem occur in android while especially dealing with bitmaps. This error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.

The size of the file on disk doesn't necessarily coincide with the size of the file in memory. Chances are likely that the file is compressed, which they won't be when decoded. You need to account for that in your calculation.

You can refer to this article on [how to load bitmaps efficiently?](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)
[How to load large bitmaps efficiently?](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

**While it's not a good idea to use** `android:largeHeap="true"` here's the extract from google that explains it,

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.

here's the complete link of the documentation
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

However, you can try to set this in andriod manifest file and run.

Comment: The weird thing is that the same code runs without error in older devices. I tested in a old galaxy ace and runs without any errors, but when the code runs in the galaxy s3,s4 or s5 the error appears. This showcaseview is a third party library and in their github they worked to fix the memory leaks in this version that I am using.